# Reading Binary File in C throws Segmentation fault

Tags: c

I am writing some code to read a binary file in c but am falling into the Segmentation Fault error. I am not so good in c and am requesting assistance from anyone here. Below is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct threeNumb
{
 int num1, num2, num3;
};
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int num;
    struct threeNumb number;
    FILE *fptr;
    if((fptr=fopen("program.bin","rb"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR OPENING FILE !");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(num=1;num<5;++num)
    {

     fread(&num,sizeof(struct threeNumb), 1, fptr);
     printf("num1:%d\tnum2: %d\tnum3:%d",number.num1,number.num2,number.num3);

    }
    fclose(fptr);
    
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `&number` in the `fread` call.

Comment: As an aside, `number` is poorly-named.  It should be `myThreeNumb` or something similar.`

Comment: @Retired Ninja true. .. Thanks. This fixes the issue. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading a 3-integer structure and storing it in a single integer (`num`). Fix your `fread` call.

Answer (score 0):

Your passing wrong variables to fread .... First argument ...